# Lagrange notation: $f^{(0)}(x)$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, notation, taylor-expansion

Using Lagrange notation, is  $f^{(0)}(x)=f(x)$? Is this standard notation, or would one have to define $f^{(0)}(x)=f(x)$ first, before using it?
Aside: the context of the question is whether to include the first term within the summation when expressing the Taylor series and hence start at $n=0$, or to write it separately outside the summation and start the summation at $n=1$.
The former has been done here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition

Comment: In [Lagrange notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Lagrange's_notation) $f(x)$ is simply $f(x)$.

Comment: But in the Taylor expansion notation using the bigsum, $f^{(0)}(x)$ is clearly $f(x)$.

Comment: I have even seen $f^{(-n)}$ for the iterated integral (or anti-derivative). If the context is clear with usage of parenthesis there is no problem identifying $f^{(0)}$ and $f$ rather than exponentiation which uses no parenthesis $f^n$. Only issue would be to differentiate from iterated composition which has no consensus scripting so either $f^n, f^{(n)}, f^{[n]}, f^{\circ^n}$ could be encountered.

Comment: I think there's a case to be made for $f^{\circ n}$ for the iterated function; I can't recall where I first saw this, or if I just made it up myself at some point.

Answer (score 2):

Writing $f^{(0)}(x)=f(x)$ just to be sure that we all agree on the same definitions is always smart to do. When in doubt specify unless it might even make things more confusing. Interpreting a function as its own zeroth derivative is not a weird thing to think about, but just mention it in case the reader is very fussy and wants to make a point about everything (knowing myself - I would). I think your reasoning is valid.

Answer (score 2):

A definition of something is always good before using it, as happend in the wikipedia article:

> The derivative of order zero of $f$ is defined to be $f$ itself.

So you can start summation at $n=0$ in Taylor series after refering to this definition. But you can put your mind at rest. Most mathematicians would expect that $f^{(0)}(x)=f(x)$ without definition.